# AngularJS using same directive element multiple times (Validation error)

Tags: angularjs, email, angularjs-directive, multiple-instances

I have prepared a form that have 2 directive elements in one form.
But the first one's validation does not work and second one's validation errors appear on both directive element.

How can I overcome this issue?
The plunk project is on given link below.

[Click for the Plunker Project](http://plnkr.co/edit/mGHh6IfvhSIu0hW1wfCs?p=preview)

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Durakhan</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('app', []);
      app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
      $scope.person = {};
    }]);
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <script src="inputEmail.js"></script>
    <script src="InputEmailCtrl.js"></script>
    <div id="Div1" class="modal" tabindex="-1" style="display: block" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="form col-md-12 center-block" name="loginForm"  novalidate>
                        <input-identityemail ng-model="person.identityemail"></input-identityemail>
                        <input-email ng-model="person.email1" required></input-email>
                        <input-email ng-model="person.email2" required></input-email>
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4" ng-class="{'has-error': loginForm.email3.$invalid}">
                          <input type="email" name="email3" ng-model="person.email3" class="form-control" ng-required="required">
                          <span ng-show="loginForm.email3.$error.required" class="help-block">Can't be blank</span>
                          <span ng-show="loginForm.email3.$error.email" class="help-block">Not a valid email</span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    Person: <pre>{{person | json}}</pre>
                    Form $error: <pre>{{loginForm.$error | json}}</pre>
                    <p>Is the form valid?: {{loginForm.$valid}}</p>
                    <p>Is 1st email valid?: {{loginForm.email1.$valid}}</p>
                    <p>Is 2nd email valid?: {{loginForm.email2.$valid}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### input-email.html

```
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
<div class="col-sm-4" ng-class="{'has-error': form.email.$invalid}">
  <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" class="form-control" ng-required="required">

  <span ng-show="form.email.$error.required" class="help-block">Can't be blank</span>
  <span ng-show="form.email.$error.email" class="help-block">Not a valid email</span>
</div>
```

### inputEmail.js

```
'use strict';

app.directive('inputEmail', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'input-email.html',
        replace: false,
        controller: 'InputEmailCtrl',
        require: ['^form', 'ngModel'],

        // See Isolating the Scope of a Directive http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive
        scope: {},

        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
            scope.form = ctrls[0];
            var ngModel = ctrls[1];

            if (attrs.required !== undefined) {
                // If attribute required exists
                // ng-required takes a boolean
                scope.required = true;
            }

            scope.$watch('email', function () {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.email);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

### inputEmailCtrl

```
'use strict';

app.controller('InputEmailCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
}]);
```

[Click for the Plunker Project](http://plnkr.co/edit/mGHh6IfvhSIu0hW1wfCs?p=preview)

thanks for answers.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/mGHh6IfvhSIu0hW1wfCs?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based in your plunker I made some changes that could help you.

index.html

```
<input-email name='email1' ng-model="person.email1" required></input-email>
<input-email name='email2' ng-model="person.email2" required></input-email>
```

input-email

```
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
<div class="col-sm-4" ng-class="{'has-error': !form.{{varName}}.dirty && form.{{varName}}.$invalid}">
      <input type="email" name="varName" ng-model="varModel" class="form-control" required>

      <span ng-show="form.{{varName}}.$error.required" class="help-block">Can't be blank</span>
      <span ng-show="form.{{varName}}.$modelValue == undefined" class="help-block">Not a valid email</span>
</div>
```

inputEmail

```
...
scope: {
          varModel: '=ngModel',
          varName: '@name'
        },

        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
            scope.form = ctrls[0];
            var ngModel = ctrls[1];

            if (attrs.required !== undefined) {
                // If attribute required exists
                // ng-required takes a boolean
                scope.required = true;
            }

            scope.$watch(scope.varModel, function () {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.varModel);
            });
...
```

Hope this help

Comment: But solution have one more problem :(
There must be one validation error while writing but both of them is seen for one control.

valid email format error and required error validation is seen at the same time. :(

Comment: Hi again;
I removed required part from input-email.html and worked.

But !form.{{varName}}.dirty does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Just writing this here in case someone encounters the same problem:

I am working in a legacy project and currently updating the AngularJS version from 1.3.x to 1.8.x. Suddenly, using multiple elements with the same directive attribute was no longer working. Only one out of all the elements was shown, and the rest was magically gone without any sign of error message or other traces.

I had three elements using the directive on it:

```
<div select-person person="one" />

<div select-person person="two" />

<div select-person person="three" />
```

My directive controller looked similar to this:

```
  angular
    .module('demo')
    .directive('selectPerson', ['customSettings', selectDirective]);

  function selectPersonDirective(customSettings) {
    return {
      templateUrl: "Directives/SelectDirective",
      scope: {
        person: '@'
      },
      bindToController: true,
      controller: selectCtrl,
      controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    };

function selectCtrl() {
   ...
}
```

The problem was that only **one** of the elements using the directives was shown. After reading every single page on StackOverflow as well as the full AngularJS documentation, I tried every possible change in the directive as I assumed that there was an issue with scope isolation.

After spending a couple of days with headache, I finally managed to resolve my issue:

I had a self-enclosing HTML tag on the directive element, instead of closing it "normally":

```
<div select-person person="one"></div>

<div select-person person="two"></div>

<div select-person person="three"></div>
```

After this, my code magically started working as it is supposed to again.